# Outlook not receiving emails

Tags: outlook.com, email, email-headers, gmx

I hope to post this in the right stack community.

Here's the problem:

A member of my familly is using an hotmail.com email address, and it seems that she doesnt receive emails since monday.
She connects through https://**outlook.com** webmail, but as she stated, **no emails received since monday**.
This is very unusual and we are pretty sure this is  **not normal, as she usually gets alot of emails (Work & subscriptions)**

I tried to send her emails: nothing.
Neither have i received a "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)" from my mailer-daemon.
**She's still able to successfully send emails**.

```
Return-Path: <XXXXXX@hotmail.com>
Received: from EUR03-AM5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com ([40.92.70.82]) by mx-ha.gmx.net (mxgmx016 [212.227.15.10]) with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id 1MNu8Y-1eCdC83P4K-00OPEC for <XXXXXX@gmx.com>; Sun, 14 Jan 2018 19:17:56 +0100
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=hotmail.com; s=selector1; h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version; bh=VNtEGtY/AeNlfftRf9G9QjOySk8jwZpQBzMWcFRj1xY=; b=tHWAE6zMYIjAs1mgDvvI8pSB+E3UFYIeJcZai0K2GOflWukJrmTFTlChzFycjGFbjvClWL3KU8N522ApbFxkXowq8ijxRahj9K1+U3CG13MEtDOKO3uF7JRUE9ETY4W7kr4mS9KjVwRLSuEZALQMHIF2t/kTaNkIT4kjmSzgfXguZ4nyhfWO63XyGAH8UPErNuRA7S3OvbzegkX6udAEL9RaVNO2+YhlXRDIA0RFjh7n+WuSpYJpJdJoI/jGzIbhA1qIyrvXOU1hYhzSQfix8WQ2hXlW74FRSr/fA792/6ucyJGt9RNm6//KQYaz7TZ/pdJ8Z7PKpUo70jkG5urgBg==
Received: from VE1EUR03FT026.eop-EUR03.prod.protection.outlook.com (10.152.18.58) by VE1EUR03HT133.eop-EUR03.prod.protection.outlook.com (10.152.19.105) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.20.345.12; Sun, 14 Jan 2018 18:17:56 +0000
Received: from AM6PR0602MB3382.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.152.18.52) by VE1EUR03FT026.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.18.148) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256) id 15.20.345.12 via Frontend Transport; Sun, 14 Jan 2018 18:17:56 +0000
Received: from AM6PR0602MB3382.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::b57c:c397:7bad:dc4]) by AM6PR0602MB3382.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::b57c:c397:7bad:dc4%13]) with mapi id 15.20.0407.009; Sun, 14 Jan 2018 18:17:56 +0000
From: XXXXXX <XXXXXX@hotmail.com>
To: Mathieu <XXXXXX@gmx.com>
Subject: test
Thread-Topic: test
Thread-Index: AQHTjWP4go8MIadcXUi6bM59HXpxRg==
Date: Sun, 14 Jan 2018 18:17:56 +0000
Message-ID: <AM6PR0602MB33820B9096C61BE50CAE6703C8150@AM6PR0602MB3382.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>
Accept-Language: fr-BE, en-US
Content-Language: fr-BE
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-incomingtopheadermarker: OriginalChecksum:783498F930EFFD0B8A56C929A099C0E9A469C9CC50D82AAA4A6737A37B36E490;UpperCasedChecksum:4DD59FA676C1B4039275EFC5BA69041C548480CCB582291CE624FC92FBE43E3E;SizeAsReceived:6802;Count:44
x-ms-exchange-messagesentrepresentingtype: 1
x-tmn: [SlCSWghtvtbW1+2kagm9+Gysn9vxMYiP]
x-ms-publictraffictype: Email
x-microsoft-exchange-diagnostics: 1;VE1EUR03HT133;7:OS2aQrVw5GztvNalZMrLPmyDwvXbfsRgmPgEMa5NnXMdqAI1hYdF85XYObDvPJ+wnCBMTjW2h3nvB8LGKKgT1/QxPrPICveehKO1piK7KCX0YlAjxa58at4o31g5BhmjoP6h429uFMx/S1PkhxnkQf0TA/ciD1cNCBzzELAaVkX1eGzgRp72ApvoH/nOxTkBUy0rC0Lo5F7k6mbIHA4I/1wvWobRB//B6GUNhRoBmbT8Rd79OhOqGy+GaM7yN74s
x-incomingheadercount: 44
x-eopattributedmessage: 0
x-microsoft-antispam: UriScan:;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(7020095)(201702061074)(5061506573)(5061507331)(1603103135)(2017031320274)(2017031324274)(2017031323274)(2017031322404)(1603101448)(1601125374)(1701031045);SRVR:VE1EUR03HT133;
x-ms-traffictypediagnostic: VE1EUR03HT133:
x-ms-office365-filtering-correlation-id: 1316d5c6-5d99-43a2-1da5-08d55b7b2295
x-exchange-antispam-report-cfa-test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(444000031);SRVR:VE1EUR03HT133;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000803101)(100110400095);SRVR:VE1EUR03HT133;
x-forefront-prvs: 05529C6FDB
x-forefront-antispam-report: SFV:NSPM;SFS:(7070007)(98901004);DIR:OUT;SFP:1901;SCL:1;SRVR:VE1EUR03HT133;H:AM6PR0602MB3382.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:;
spamdiagnosticoutput: 1:99
spamdiagnosticmetadata: NSPM
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_000_AM6PR0602MB33820B9096C61BE50CAE6703C8150AM6PR0602MB3382_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OriginatorOrg: hotmail.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 1316d5c6-5d99-43a2-1da5-08d55b7b2295
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-originalarrivaltime: 14 Jan 2018 18:17:56.1627 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-fromentityheader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: VE1EUR03HT133
Envelope-To: <XXXXXX@gmx.com>
X-GMX-Antispam: 0 (Mail was not recognized as spam); Detail=V3;
X-UI-Filterresults: notjunk:1;V01:K0:Eb/VwBdQotM=:3AoyMOMxc/o3a1leJvy1pxpBpQ u8xvr3VT4dtQS9joxUpqRrMMvsPv4e49Gpj+L2oxZGi9f8WPBqyfJ7xDeZWeAlFoZ8+ft+Egf pBrCAacA5L4mbYQS3JMD5+J4xbAsW2Ao+y632zoKOo+fJbBZ+rFSvkpMlUibtMD+bOTrp0/vV Tef4SLaI2F7nXf6Nz1P45nvp+JCEwZKU5Gh9Ptb3Ma+imoNGbDQghZNBs7K4ynZzobM3uTbAG FKs4dkemxeYsssaF1vRLzMe2XYBMhl9LRJu0S2cusvdYTJrRIq7s5LNk9UfxyTM675+5KRx/e fCed4oYsj7H51TDqx19LFqZc6d+XjOt8drr97blP2FjnE7Scexx4pFwe+5gYuGsr+ZI1DNO09 JHyzMOpg7uJKZZqKvr5DB/rBex58OhyP8RK8Wb1wIQuve2C8KRYsgjiyzrVOuCzVSlnd9tqU9 U1UFRIO5f+piq+ahUogjeG7+jMCvNKuoJbDxcU5JbzjEdjORDH/aDmB6KfiLmtu1vVAG/VPzu qKOw+MVi5o9XZLGq5g6iWIdL8AmlD04LheePrH/S9Md6DtzsXO03/yq6GWzpe3DuL0TKirUDY SoHvyO5DEtxcBrHCqrWFvPmqbRHNl5ofWSpGgsS5DBan+wLSHMBhsQQxJS3KRjXSwCwH0YLxl phYNOGL0wHAaXhxb6AG3UgOJtZxtJ3UPD2w39gVEmDK6aaAnhojsYc6XNwUgdNiTxqM6QHNqY pQobcrJFkr0eDX3PCcraqyOufyEL7QOiJOGSJRF+hKEF6VmBTuJvaexnEhTaoNPhuImGDUJ8k 3VJ/HC4pLW9dH9Xdg5bHW1vUgrhmiYEKYLR2lDePIMLnuuZxEYjt4bV7EaxtF2V7ov3ld3vaV en/tnhCv1/O7P8Wo6UBm8XUonfz7udvxLjTm4PneSy4vwXkf92+0T9RkArYkwG8AUb4xHpU1o +obMGUT6LvPrrfm7LUWf3K10DwZZd1iJSZYZ9TLr/iRCTEjv3FHED9zAbUm31ilxQyNLjg+uc pOQW9eBJyHp/kEsK+idOrjsNkFkX5BcTDeFLmeJCSE8eQhxYvevyQiQNMZQkUTJeHGzAeemyr 6YcFZ1qW2NqVYT1653M/LqM0VtBUloind1Olgh5aQ8VBxsewNyOtyZVx84dC1zUryqK2V1SnP SIcbhTg9b3vRHXZF6Un6l0YReYB6BLGTzZh0CLeLyDKWeG018FMw5Fq6bQMYp3U/M9lFXPXwU z/AsaYzztjMeTPNBbjfr17dh/BB5eIT5FlBaUCnm6Mvh84hv28oexsWS1cKTJ2MJgDOSd5SJ+ a3PaL4GFok4lWBCeIetvp9OyWhowMA+RONCIuJ6YDQ3yMJ9WJXpJgUbOgVKmyzNb70KxNn1Md 7+j+GdWOeixR9x15of1ujpa5wVLn6cfTQC9cfv1Y5vH5U3ckGBuFAZAgNXMRq59fGlmZAdo4L UlF1nE65pGJTCrt8i6Fh0BVkdgQlbKXOxzyJ0kHjETuAe6SGt4slQV7IjTSioO9ACW4fkWQ0Z Dm55c8SlaDe+hZA77oYqdFGVQ8RDfhCUU0iu1zIa03lY0fnfYP+b1IukLnBwqQC3TxgbrMQPK ozic7ivOStOORoMdpJbew/2IpJgmBpMW4HJy8x9tNZ+iHICwFgCgQ16rO4zU/YI7kR585Ry83 ef2DO9jnfVQH+9nLc64OcIoLE++rtqXcSUZy0TjKAZ7xVBoZq9xsEZJQf7hM9nk4TC8Ojr3eo wVYo9n1dJfLC93rk9Jc9hWi9AB4YaeiWfgIhquxEboJ6CKuCMtm+WXRImeGef39PDdVl5e13P wX13z37ETTe5NZ58Pe1t46pSyD9/cLJaRrSPKwiHv0hjI66+HBdp7ThRNPec0Z5eNNW5Q
```

Comment: Has this person set up POP or IMAP access recently?

Comment: A month ago, she set up her new iphone 6+ and used her hotmail address (with the default iphone mail app). At the begining it was working fine, but maybe a week later, she was unable to send emails from her phone. Mails were stuck in outbox.

Comment: It seems likely that all of the messages are being downloaded via POP on to the Mail app and deleted off of the server.  You'll probably have to adjust the settings on Apple Mail to either get mail via IMAP (which won't download and delete them) or configure POP to leave them on the server.  I don't think the issue is with Outlook.com here, honestly.

Comment: She does not receive emails on her iphone neither.
She says that she was able to read emails on both iphone/ipad/computer untill this monday.

Comment: Now i'm able to click on "reply" from her email. Maybe you're right and it is a pop/imap misconfiguration, but since she does not get email anywhere, how can we pinpoint the problem ?

Comment: So the emails are stuck on either the iPad or the desktop (I'm assuming it's a Mac) and are being downloaded there currently.  Not sure beyond that how to puzzle this out.